# e.preventDefault(); undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the following error that is saying my `e.preventDefault();` `--->` "`e.`" `undefined is not a function` when clicking `<button class='url_qry_add' onclick='url_qry_add(this);'>`. The function itself is defined before the end of my `</body>` and I have only invoked jQuery once.

The function structure is as follows:

```
var url_qry_add = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
};
```

It used to be:

```
$( "ul.url_qry" ).on( "click", "li .url_qry_add", function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

But subsequent buttons added dynamically afterwards were not being picked up.

So I've been trying to figure out how to go about it and decided I should try converting the problem function to a named "invokable" function and putting the call in manually with the `onclick='..'` into the buttons that exist before and after dynamic creation.

Like I say, the error must be in the way I've created the function or the way I'm calling it. The error can't be to do with the order of files and I have not accidentally nested the function within another function or a `document.ready`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<button class='url_qry_add' onclick='url_qry_add(event);'>

var url_qry_add = function (e) {
    console.log(typeof e.preventDefault); // function 
};
```

**Update:**

I'll try clarify how it works "internally", when we add attributes to function url_qry_add "inside" it looks like this:

```
document.querySelector('.url_qry_add').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  (function (event) {
    url_qry_add(event, this, $(this));
  }).call(event.target, event);
});

var url_qry_add = function (event, element, $jElement) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(element);
  console.log($jElement);
};
```

Hence, we have variable "*event*" (event object, where we have method *preventDefault* and so on), and "*this*" (current element). I hope that this explanation will help you understand where we get variable "*event*".